# Including header files in C++

Tags: c++, header-files

I'm very new to C++ and I've just figured out that main() is meant to call all the header functions.

I've made 5 header files, all .hpp, and placed them in the header folder of my project. As you can see they all have the same extension and location:

[image]

But when I call the header files in my main.cpp file... only getline_demo.hpp can be found by the system:

[image]

The error is "cannot open filename.hpp" for the others.

What could be happening and how could I fix it?

Comment: Please include your code in place, no links to code images. Also, your main() conclusion is very wrong, please start with a good C++ book.

Comment: Also include the exact error messages (by copy/pasting them). Don't put images directly in the question either. Put the actual code in the question by copy/pasting it and using the format `{}` button. Read this chapter [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: My *guess* is that the location *on disk* of the other header files is not the same as the "main.cpp" file.

Comment: What you're showing is VS's "filters" view, which is its own imaginary file system and is not actually used for anything but display. Tick the "Show All Files" button in the Solution Explorer toolbar to see where the files *actually* are.

Comment: An `#include` puts the content of a file into another file. That is all it does. This is required when some definition is to be known, like a function declaration. You only need to include headers from which you use stuff. If this is news to you, please start with the basic tutorials before you do anything else. As for your question, the include folders need to be specified in the Makefile, or in some sort of project file from which the Makefile is created, like a Qt project file. Maybe state which IDE you are using there. A "project" is not an objective term here, from a technical pov.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this:

1) Easiest: just put the fullpath from disk

```
#include "C:\... "
```

2) Inside the properties of the project C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories the full path to the folder containing the files

2') You can use macros that specifies the project dir, solution dir ...

Answer (score 0):

The `main()` function is not meant to *"call all the header functions"*.

You don't have any error here (assuming your files are in the same folder which seems to be the case here).
You are using the Visual Studio Code's editor. It seems that your editor is misconfigured and could not find the files in its own file tree representation, that's all.

---

**EDIT:**

If you have an include error at compilation, then this is that you missed to specify the paths correctly. For example, if you have the "main.cpp" alongside an "include" folder that contains your .hpp files, you will have to include the one you want this way:

```
#include "include/my_header.hpp"
```

Always give **relative paths**.

Comment: I want to disagree with this a bit. When including header files `<>` symbols are usually used for third party libraries while `" "` are used for user written headers. I think this is just the best practice. At this situation `#include "include/my_header.hpp"` should be used.

Comment: @Cactus'as You are right, my bad, a typo. In fact, `" "` are preferred because it searches in the user folder in priority in contrary to with `< >` that searches in system installed libraries folder at first.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot it looks like `getline_demo.hpp` can be fond by your IDE, check using your file explorer where the files are placed and move the others into the same folder.

Never use absolute paths in your project/source files unless you want to cause problems for yourself and others in the future!

Also remember that the views IDEs give you of your project may not correlate to the layout on the filesystem - which is the layout your compiler cares about!

Special thanks go to Microsoft Visual Studio for the "helpful" filters it creates.